# the Intel C/C++ compilers throw error during array initialization

Tags: c++, c, intel, icc

I have regular C++ code for an array initialization to a value that compiles fine with the latest gnu compiler on Cygwin:

```
int main(){
    x = 10;
    int my_array[x][x][x] = {0};
    double my_other_array[x][x][x][x] = {0.};
    return 0;
}
```

However, when I transfer it over to the cluster and do the intel compiler (with all the fancy stuff for the mic coprocessors), the code will not compile, and it fails with the following error:

> error: variable "my_array" may not be initialized

The error message disappears when I put the actual integers in the array box, rather than the variable.

However, the housing function of my arrays (in the actual code, not my example) gets called with inputs which determine the sizes of the array...so, while the array size does not change during the execution, I can't just put numbers in the array boxes (er, brackets)--they need to be the variables.

---

How to I implement this functionality with the intel compilers?

Comment: What do you mean "array boxes"?  Do you mean the initializer list, the stuff inside the `{}`?

Comment: yeah, the bracketed region in the declaration: `my_array [this part]`, but not the braces

Comment: try `x = 10;` --> `const int x = 10;`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY ah thanks man...will try that...

Comment: Those are called the array dimensions, or the array size.

Comment: `x = 10;` is an error which should be diagnosed by the compiler - pay attention to its messages

Comment: Please clarify whether you are writing C or C++, they are different languages

Comment: @bordeo -- *How to I implement this functionality with the intel compilers?* -- Do you really want to?  IMO, using `std::vector` is far superior than using invalid C++ syntax.  For one, you wouldn't have needed to post a question here if you started out using `std::vector`, since the code would have worked on any ANSI standard C++ compiler.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie great, thanks--I am in an high performance computing class, and this is my first semester with C++ (4th week).

Comment: @bordeo -- The other reason to start using vector is that you can easily blow out the stack if `x` is too large for the VLA, and you're declaring local VLA's.  Last, VLA's still leaves you vulnerable to out-of-bounds accesses, while at least `vector` has an `at()` function to check for these errors.  There are many posts here where the poster uses VLA's, and the usage of them caused stack issues, or produced programs that "worked", but on closer inspection was accessing elements out-of-bounds.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie lol, I might have just run into that.  got a segmentation fault running on the coprocessor, but not my i7 machine.  thank you for the heads up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The use of variable sized arrays is a compiler extension and is not a standard C++ language feature.  (It is a standard feature of newer specifications of the C language.)  This is not supported in the Intel compiler.

To declare the variable sized arrays you'll need to use std::vector or something similar.

Comment: I thought ICC supported GNU C++ language extensions in general.  Is there no way to enable it?

Comment: Even in C, initializers are not allowed with VLAs

Comment: @PeterCordes It took me a while, but I think I found a reference in the Intel documentation that says VLAs are included with the Cilk Plus feature, which are part of the Intel language extensions, which are on by default.  There was a forum post that implied that only one index (the first?) of multi dimensional arrays can be variable, but I haven't found where in the docs it says that.